# Adjust RStudio console width programmatically

Tags: r, console, rstudio

I'm using tibble's `glimpse` function that prints output adjusted to RStudio's console width. To get the most descriptive output, I want RStudio's console width to be large (something like 180).

How do I set the width using code and not manually? `getOption("width")` or `options("width")[[1]]` returns the width, but I cannot set it to a value as that throws an error.

Edit: I've even tried setting width using `options("width" = 180)`. This step although edits width parameter but does not expand RStudio's console.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot resize windows programatically (yet?).

Answer (score 2):

To change the `width option`, use

```
options(width = 180)
```

Comment: Hi Jozef, its setting the width successfully. But RStudio does not adjust even after editing the width. Can you also tell how to adjust RStudio with code?

Comment: Ah, I understood you wanted to change the `width` option, which is also very useful. I am not aware one can control RStudio's layout programatically (yet), as this does not seem to be not accessible via `rstudioapi`.

Comment: No need (and, indeed, no sense) to quote the `width` argument. It’s a name, not a character string.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, indeed, I updated my answer, thanks.